# I am getting a problem in vs code regarding code writing after update

Tags: visual-studio-code

I updated my vs code last night and after that they prohibited me to write some certain word in the code.

1. I am unable to write "Node" in the c code
2. I am unable to write "endl " in my c++ program.

It is taking this words by copy paste, but for this too short word why i will use copy paste and waste my time.

I have reset my vs code, done restricted mode false,
but no response.
Same is happening.

I am using windows 11.

Comment: Please share the exact code you are trying to write and the exact error messages you encounter ...

Comment: Thanks to you, but its now ok . someone has changed a shortcut key to d of my vs code that's why it was so .